# Toolbar icons and text not appearing

Tags: tinymce

In the image, you can see all the icons and text are missing from the toolbar, with the exception of the chevrons.

1. I do not believe it is a .svg issue (per Tiny.com FAQs) because the chevrons are also svg.
2. I have 3 instances of the TinyMCE editor on this site and the icons are missing in all 3.
3. TinyMCE version 6.1.2 (2022-07-29)

This is not all that helpful, but this issue appeared suddenly—they have been appearing just fine for weeks.

[image: TinyMCE icons not appearing]

```
HTML:
<textarea name="resources" id="resources" class="tiny-mce-lite"></textarea>

JQUERY:
tinymce.init({
    selector: 'textarea.tiny-mce-lite',
    height: '200',
    width: '700',
    statusbar: false,
    menubar: false,
    plugins : 'lists link moxiemanager image media',
    toolbar: 'undo redo | blocks fontsize bold italic | image media',
    content_css : "/css/editor.css",
    image_advtab: true,
    browser_spellcheck : true,
    extended_valid_elements : "i[class|aria-hidden]"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Explanation:

Elsewhere in my form, I use `<span></span>` to show error messages that are, by default, `display: none`. If an error is returned, javascript displays the `<span>` and the error.

```
/* HTML */
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class="first_name">
<span></span>

/* in CSS */
form span {
    display: none;
}
```

Enter the Inspector where I discovered all the icons in the TinyMCE toolbars are wrapped in a `<span>`.

```
<span class="tox-icon tox-tbtn__icon-wrap"><svg width="24" height="24" focusable="false">...
```

The lesson here is to always be specific using such common elements by adding a class or id—never assume. Hence:

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" value="" class="first_name">
<span class="error_msg"></span>
```